# What does the * symbol mean after void. What does adding void* do for the function?

Tags: c++

If `void*` makes a pointer that holds the address of any type, what does adding `void*` to the start of the function mean, why not just put `void`?

```
void* myFunction(void* arg)
{
    int thread_id = *((int*) arg);
```

Comment: Please add the full definition of the function, or at least the `return` statement at the end of the function if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

`void *myFunction()` means that `myFunction` returns "pointer to void", i.e. it returns a pointer, for which the type pointed to is not specified.

`void myFunction()` means that `myFunction` returns "void", i.e. it returns nothing at all.

Comment: It might have been better if the designers of C had chosen different names for these concepts, e.g. `arbitrary` for any type and `none` for no type.  It would then be more clear that `arbitrary *myFunction()` returns a pointer, and `none myFunction()` returns nothing.  But they didn't, so we're stuck with `void` playing both roles.

Comment: `using none = void;` and `using arbitrary = void*;` :)